# Upload text file into webpage using vba

Tags: vba, excel

How to upload a text file in webpage that already saved on my desktop..?
Please provide me vba codes to click on webpage on "browse..." button, then upload text file that saved on my desktop and click on submit to run a report, and after that text file run, I want to download that report.(it will take like 10 mins to run that report), and reference number to download that report is unknown..!
please advice.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your goal, you could use the following structure:

1 - Use mouse move/click APIs to simulate mouse clicks at the right spots and at the right order. To learn more about that, please refer to [Mouse Move and Click API](http://excelhelphq.com/how-to-move-and-click-the-mouse-in-vba)

2 - Use commands to synchronize the events, If you have to wait a few seconds before doing something (such as click somewhere and then wait 2 seconds and finally click somewhere else), I suggest you to use the command Application.Wait(). If you have to wait a bunch of time such as 10 minutes before doing some other action, I suggest you to use the Application.OnTime() command. Check the examples below:

```
Sub Test()

    MsgBox "Starting Now"

    Application.Wait Now + TimeSerial(0, 0, 2) 'This code will stop the code for 2 seconds (keep in mind that this will hold the thread and excel will be unresponsive for 2 seconds).

    MsgBox "2 seconds have passed!"

    Application.OnTime Now + TimeSerial(0, 1, 0), "OtherProcedureName" 'This code will run the Sub OtherProcedureName below one minute after this code runs.

End Sub

Sub OtherProcedureName()

    MsgBox "1 minute have passed!"

End Sub
```

I hope this information helps you coding your needs.